# Babel / Typescript aliases not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, babeljs

I have a Typescript environment which i compile using Gulp, tsify, browserify and babelify. I have successfully configured aliases to navigate the project better.

I am trying to import a node module, lets say `query-string`, into `component.ts` by doing this:

`import * as querystring from 'query-string';`

The `traceResolution` option of `tsconfig.json` shows me this:

> Module name 'query-string' was successfully resolved to '/node_modules/query-string/index.js'

But I'm still getting an error in the console saying:

> Error: Cannot find module 'query-string' from '/components/example-component/'

Imagine the project structure like this:

```
/
|-- node_modules/
|
|-- ts/
|    |-- app.ts //this is the main file, it imports component.ts
|
|-- components/
|    |-- example-component/
|        |-- component.html
|        |-- component.ts //attempting to import a node module here
|
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- tsconfig.json
|-- .babelrc
|-- package.json
```

My `tsconfig.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es2015",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./ts",
    "traceResolution": true,
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["../components/*"],
      "*": ["../node_modules/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

My `.babelrc` looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "cwd": "babelrc",
      "root": ["./ts"],
      "alias": {
        "@components": "./components"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Here is what actually does work:

1. importing `.ts` files using relative paths
2. importing `.ts` files using aliases (eg. `import '@component/example-component/component.ts'`)
3. importing a node module into `app.ts`

Comment: Can you add some more details? **It would be great to know:** Whether the error comes from TypeScript, from Babel, or is raised at runtime. Why you are mapping `node_modules` under `paths` (usually a mistake). If you have tried setting the TypeScript `--moduleResolution` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Successfully locating a module's entry point, which is what is correctly happening based on the `traceResolution` message you provided, is a separate problem from understanding that module.

For TypeScript to understand the module it needs to find a typings file (`.d.ts`) that describes the module's types.

Looking at the [query-string](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string) repo, it does not ship with a `.d.ts` file included, so you will need to pull it in from elsewhere.

It does, however, appear that the typings for query-string are available in the [Definitely Typed repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/query-string), meaning that you should be able to run `npm install --save-dev @types/query-string` and the typings will be added to your project.

Comment: Understood, but I'm pretty sure it's possible to get around that using `import * as`. The thing is, I can import it without a problem (same method) in the `app.ts` file. Just not in the component.

Comment: It looks to me that I can go from `app.ts` to everywhere, but going from `component.ts` using aliases or a `node_module` import is not possible. Imagine I had another component which I try to include like this: `import '@component/another-component/component.ts'`. It does work in `app.ts` but it doesn't in `component.ts`.